# Set session values with query result in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

I have a function in my model that checks the credentials given in the login form. It selects the `email`, `senha` and `tipo_pessoa`. Below is the function:

```
public function find_credentials()
{
    $this->db
        ->select('email, senha, tipo_pessoa')
        ->from($this->table)
        ->where('email', $this->input->post('email'))
        ->where('senha', md5($this->input->post('password')));

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The next function, located in my Controller, is executed regardless of the results of the previous function. It decides what to do depending on the returned result:

```
public function validate_credentials()
{
    if ($this->Usuarios_fisica_model->find_credentials()) {
        $data = array();
        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Bem-vindo!');

        redirect('/', 'refresh');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Desculpe, credenciais inválidas');
        redirect('/');
    }
}
```

I need to store `tipo_pessoa` in the session to determine which page the user should be redirected to. I have two different tables for two different kind of users, and each kind has its own page.

**Edit***

After the suggested solutions, I added to my header file the following code to echo the `tipo_pessoa`:

```
<div class="menu_login">
    <?php if ($this->session->userdata('email')) { ?>
        <span><?php echo $this->session->userdata('email'); ?></span>
        <span><?php echo $this->session->userdata('tipo_pessoa'); ?></span>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('usuario/painel'); ?>" class="bt_entre">Ir ao Painel</a>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('usuario/sair') ?>" class="bt_cadastre">Sair</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <span>Minha Conta</span>
        <a href="#" id="bt_entrar" class="bt_entre">Entre</a>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('cadastro') ?>" class="bt_cadastre">Cadastre-se</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What type of data is `tipo_pessoa`? int? string?

Comment: where in your code is `$this->session->set_userdata('tipo_pessoa', $tipo_pessoa);`?

Comment: @Kisaragi I did exactly as you've answered.

Comment: Then your model method must be returning `False`, as the session data is only set if it returns `!False`

Comment: @Kisaragi It's correct because the `validate_credentials()` checks if `find_credentials()` returns `true`, then sets the session with the e-mail, and it does set.

Answer (score 1):

Use this changes in Model:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

and make this changes to controller:

```
$data = $this->Usuarios_fisica_model->find_credentials();
if(!empty($data))
{
   $tipo_pessoa = $data[0]['tipo_pessoa']; //Get value of tipo_pessoa
   $this->session->set_userdata('tipo_pessoa', $tipo_pessoa);//Set value in session
   //your if part code
}
else
{
   //your else part code
}
```

Comment: Also echoes nothing if I try to see it. <?php echo $this->session->userdata('tipo_pessoa'); ?>

Comment: Tried to upvote this, not sure why it went negative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to set session data from the results of a query:

```
function get_something()
{
   $this->db->select('something'); 
   $something = $this->db->get('table')->row();
   $this->session->set_userdata('something',$something);
}
```

With your example model:

```
$this->db
    ->select('email, senha, tipo_pessoa')
    ->from($this->table)
    ->where('email', $this->input->post('email'))
    ->where('senha', md5($this->input->post('password')));

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    return $query->result_array();
}

return false;
```

controller:

```
if ($something = $this->Usuarios_fisica_model->find_credentials()) {
    $data = array();
    $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
    $this->session->set_userdata('tipo_pessoa', $something['tipo_pessoa']);
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Bem-vindo!');

    redirect('/', 'refresh');
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Desculpe, credenciais inválidas');
    redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to echo the session->userdata('tipo_pessoa'), but it displays nothing.

Comment: I did in my header file, where contains the logged in e-mail. I am also trying to display the `tipo_pessoa`, just for testing. `<?php echo $this->session->userdata('tipo_pessoa'); ?>`

Comment: You need to add all relevant code to the question. I don't see you setting anything other than  a `$data` array that contains the index `email`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing what I intended to do, I simply put a `select` box in the login page to choose between the two different types. Now it is easy to retrieve the value and make the choices.